# Angular: Why should I use 'encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native'?

Tags: angular, dom, shadow-dom

In Angular, the default mode is
`encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`

This mode enables styles encapsulation by using CSS selectors. However,  'encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native' also implements style encapsulation, but with another technique, shadow DOM. Whereas the technique is different, the result is the same.

If so, why should I use "ViewEncapsulation.Native"? What do I get in this mode that I don't get in "ViewEncapsulation.Emulated" ?

Answer (score 3):

With "Native" encapsulation you get all the features provided by the new Shadow DOM specification.

[This blog article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html) explains the differences between the different modes in Angular2.

Because Emulated mimics the Native mode, you'll get all the features *that can be emulated*.

What cannot be emulated is *real* CSS encapsulation (a rule with an `!important` directive could be applied to your Emulated component), and scoped selection (with the help of `querySelector()`).

With the Native mode, rendering should be faster (because it is... native!).

Comment: So, As of Nov, 2018, I can/should always use native view encapsulation ?